# package python to be installed to custom location

Tags: python-3.x, build, rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

My objective is to build a python rpm that can install to custom location on rhel 6 box.

I have take source from https://dl.iuscommunity.org/pub/ius/stable/Redhat/6/SRPMS/python34u-3.4.3-2.ius.el6.src.rpm

rpmbuild with prefix of /tmp/python/new_install succeeded in packaging.
When I try to install rpm, I am encountering circular dependency.

Install of ABCpython34u-3.4.3-2.ius.el6.x86_64.rpm gives

```
error: Failed dependencies:
    ABCpython34u-libs(x86-64) = 3.4.3-2.ius.el6 is needed by ABCpython34u-3.4.3-2.ius.el6.x86_64
    libpython3.4m.so.1.0()(64bit) is needed by ABCpython34u-3.4.3-2.ius.el6.x86_64
```

Install of ABCpython34u-libs-3.4.3-2.ius.el6.x86_64.rpm gives

```
error: Failed dependencies:
    /tmp/python/new_install/bin/python3.4 is needed by ABCpython34u-libs-3.4.3-2.ius.el6.x86_64
```

Any guidance is much appreciated.

Update:

```
/bin/rpm -i --noscripts -v ABCpython34u-libs-3.4.3-2.ius.el6.x86_64.rpm ABCpython34u-3.4.3-2.ius.el6.x86_64.rpm 2>&1
error: Failed dependencies:
    libpython3.4m.so.1.0()(64bit) is needed by ABCpython34u-3.4.3-2.ius.el6.x86_64

$ rpm -q --provides -p ABCpython34u-libs-3.4.3-2.ius.el6.x86_64.rpm|grep libpython3.4m.so.1.0
libpython3.4m.so.1.0()(64bit)(ABC)
```

Comment: What format  the provides lists?  looks like its not able to identify because of (ABC)

Comment: What wrapping tool are you talking about? Do you use it when you build the RPMs too? Did you use it for both of those RPMs?

Comment: No i just use it to deploy, i build it using rpmbuild

Comment: I'm not sure what that `(ABC)` on that requirement is but it seems to be the problem. How did you get that there? I don't see anything like that on any of the standard packages provides entries. (I assume `FDS` is the actual prefix here and you just missed that in that error line?)

Comment: ABC is a custom prefix that i got by replacing the find-provides with a custom script

Comment: I think its happening because i haven't used a custom finds-requires which would have lead it to find the dependencies in correct namespace

Comment: If you customized `find-provides` to output a custom provides entry for your symbols and didn't update `find-requires` to do the same modification then yes, that certainly seems like it could cause this problem.

Comment: @EtanReisner post above comment as an answer, I will accept it. Thanks very much

Comment: With questions like this I'm always hard-pressed to come up with a way to write up the answer so that it makes sense to anyone else in the future. It might be better for you to write up the answer yourself and include the information about the custom `find-provides` which added the extra namespace tag and how fixing `find-requires` to look for matching namespace tags fixed the problem. (I could do it but you are possibly in a better position to narrate the story of what you did and why.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to install them together:

```
  yum install ./ABCpython34u-3.4.3-2.ius.el6.x86_64.rpm ./ABCpython34u-libs-3.4.3-2.ius.el6.x86_64.rpm
```

But what you are doing (python in custom location) is very likely wrong. If you want to have recent python on RHEL6 box you very likely want Software Collection:

https://www.softwarecollections.org/en/

https://www.softwarecollections.org/en/scls/rhscl/rh-python34/

Comment: I dont have root to update system python. So i am rolling out my own.

Comment: Then just use: rpm -i --noscripts ./ABCpython34u-3.4.3-2.ius.el6.x86_64.rpm ./ABCpython34u-libs-3.4.3-2.ius.el6.x86_64.rpm

Comment: @technocrattobe How are you intending to install RPMs without root? Software collections don't update the system python. They complement the system python.

Comment: There ia a tool that wraps around rpm , basically checks for name spacing (prefix ABC) before handing over to rpm.